# In a text field, replace words that start with one character and end with another

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, replace

I would like in a text field to replace all sequences starting with a character, ending with another character and with a certain length. I tried the following code and it does not work, can you help me please.

Thanks for your help.

I try :

```
WITH data_set AS 
(  
   SELECT "KJHKJHJK ABBC : HKJHKJHJKH" AS C1, 
   UNION ALL
   SELECT "jlkjlkjj AHJC : iuoiu iouiou" AS C1, 
   UNION ALL
   SELECT "oioijoijoj BXBC : gguygyuguyg"AS C1
) 
SELECT
    C1,
    CASE
        WHEN C1 LIKE '%A%:%' THEN REPLACE (C1 ,'A____:', 'AAAA :') 
        WHEN C1 LIKE '%B%:%' THEN REPLACE (C1 ,'B____:', 'BBBB :') 
        ELSE C1
    END AS C1_REWORKED
FROM 
    data_set
```

In the example what I wanted to code is:

- If column `C1` contains a word starting with A followed by 4 characters (whatever they are) and ending with ":" then replace this string with "AAAA :"

OR

- If column `C1` contains a word starting with B followed by 4 characters (whatever they are) and ending with ":" then replace this string with "BBBB :"

(knowing that I can not have A****: and B****: in the same columns)

In what I coded parameters 'A____:' and 'B____:' seems not taken into account in the REPLACE instructions

Result was :

```
C1                              C1_REWORKED 
KJHKJHJK ABBC : HKJHKJHJKH      KJHKJHJK ABBC : HKJHKJHJKH
jlkjlkjj AHJC : iuoiu iouiou    jlkjlkjj AHJC : iuoiu iouiou
oioijoijoj BXBC : gguygyuguyg   oioijoijoj BXBC : gguygyuguyg
```

Expected result :

```
C1                              C1_REWORKED 
KJHKJHJK ABBC : HKJHKJHJKH      KJHKJHJK AAAA : HKJHKJHJKH
jlkjlkjj AHJC : iuoiu iouiou    jlkjlkjj AAAA : iuoiu iouiou
oioijoijoj BXBC : gguygyuguyg   oioijoijoj BBBB : gguygyuguyg
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regexp_replace and regexp_contains function, like that

```
WITH data_set AS 
(  SELECT "KJHKJHJK ABBC : HKJHKJHJKH" AS C1, 
   UNION ALL
   SELECT "jlkjlkjj AHJC : iuoiu iouiou" AS C1, 
   UNION ALL
   SELECT "oioijoijoj BXBC : gguygyuguyg"AS C1
) 

SELECT
C1,
CASE
  WHEN REGEXP_CONTAINS(C1,r'A+.* :') THEN regexp_replace(C1, r'A+.* :', 'AAAA :') 
  WHEN REGEXP_CONTAINS(C1,r'B+.* :') THEN regexp_replace(C1, r'B+.* :', 'BBBB :') 
  ELSE C1
  END AS C1_REWORKED
FROM data_set
```

Comment: Maybe one question more, could you tell me what is the function of "r" in parameter : " r'A+.* :' " ?

Comment: It's to indicate that is a regexp string expression